# Replace a Paragraph After a String

Tags: terminal, grep, sed

I have a text file with a lot of lines and paragraphs

I want to replace a string with a line of string

Example:

Old Text File

```
Sometexts
```

New Text File

```
Sometexts
With Some Lines
Paragraphs
and Some Thing More
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Please add more detail to this question - your description says "replace" but you are just adding to the end.  Why can't you cut and paste or just type in the additional text?

Comment: I don't understand why you have multiple `files` in your example (old text file and new text file). What does the old text file have to do with the new text file? Are you after a method to read data from one to the other?

Comment: Nope I Just Want to Add Some Paragraphs to a Text File After a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I assume you want to replace

```
sometexts
```

with

```
Sometexts
With Some Lines
Paragraphs
and Some Thing More
```

If so, you can use `Notepadd++`

So, assuming you want to update every time the word `sometexts` appears, press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the find box. Select the Replace tab.

In the `Find what` box, type in the word you want to find (`sometexts`) and in the `Replace with` box, add the new text. To add new lines, add `\n` for each new line.

Then, in search mode, select `Extended`

[image]

And I click Replace All, it updates to:

[image]

Comment: Thanks For The Answer
but i want to do this by bash

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the new text is in a file named "newtext.txt":

```
sed '/Sometexts/ r newtext.txt' old.txt > new.txt
```

For 2nd occurrence only, sed won't do. awk is perfectly suitable:

```
$ cat old.txt
one
Sometexts
two
Sometexts
three
Sometexts
four

$ cat newtext.txt 
With Some Lines
Paragraphs
and Some Thing More 

$ awk '{print} /Sometexts/ && ++n==2 {while (getline < "newtext.txt") print}' old.txt
one
Sometexts
two
Sometexts
With Some Lines
Paragraphs
and Some Thing More 
three
Sometexts
four
```

Comment: Hi This Thing Really Works but What if i want to replace the 'Sometexts' string on the 2nd Occurrence Only?